# Friendbot url - Horizon

Tags: horizon

I am setting up horizon in local for a private network. How to I configure friendbot url?

Can anyone please explain working of this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the friendbot [docs](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/friendbot#friendbot-service-for-the-stellar-test-network):

> Horizon needs to be started with the following command line param: --friendbot-url="http://localhost:8004/" This will forward any query params received against /friendbot to the friendbot instance.

If you run your friendbot service at that location, Horizon will correctly forward requests there. If you need the friendbot service binary, you can download it from [Stellar go releases](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases) and run it, or build it from source in the usual way for go services.

Comment: I did that, but no process with port 8004 is running. How will the process be called? I am getting connection refused because of that.